I can not run a vite project after I have configured it for Docker
I am having an issue with Vite that I have never seen before and need some help.
I have a project with two folders, Backend and Frontend, Backend folder works fine, the problem is with the Frontend folder.
I have Vite with React and Tailwind and I have configured the Frontend project for Docker, to be able to create an image and I have done it correctly, it works, the problem that I have now is when I try to run the Frontend project on my laptop, I can not, it automatically stops.
Here is an image to explain it:

The problem is when I type npm run dev is automatically killed, but I do not know why.
I checked my ram and CPU and is only at 40% of usage, I also restart my computer.
Here is my vite.config.js file
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
     host: '0.0.0.0',
     port: 3000,
  },
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.html']
})

Does anyone have an idea what could happen?

It's not too clear to me but, are you trying to run the development server from your host (directly on the terminal) or from the docker container?

On the terminal

Have you tried running npm run dev with another shell other than zsh? What about removing node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall the dependencies with npm install? I highly doubt Docker was the culprit here, maybe you installed a new dependency that is not compatible with your computer? It kinda looks like you're trying to run a binary that was not built for your architecture.

Okay, after one day of trying I have discovered the solution.
I do not remember when or why but I needed to run two commands as 'sudo' to integrate Vite server with Docker and, one of that, was sudo npm install to update some packages, so, after that, to run vite again I ONLY need to do sudo npm run dev. That's all.
Thank a lot to all and sorry to bother you.

Try with these configs
 host: true,
 port: 8000,


can you add the dockerfile also to the question
